# Use cases for undefineds when only using consts in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, constants, undefined, ecmascript-6

If we never use `var` variables in JavaScript and we only use `const` constants, when would the `undefined` data type come up? One example is when hoisting a constant:

```
console.log(a)
const a = 5
```

would print `undefined` to the console. Another example (written in the console) is

```
> function test(a, b) { console.log(a, b) }
undefined
> test(1)
1 undefined
undefined
```

`function` definitions and `const` definitions return `undefined`. In fact, any function that doesn't return a value returns `undefined` when called. And calling a function with fewer parameters than expected will assign `undefined` to the remaining parameters.

When else would `undefined` be used? Is there a list of `undefined` use cases somewhere?

Comment: Just to clarify, your first example would actually throw an exception in a correct ES6 environment, because you cannot access `a` before its declaration has been initialized. `const` and `let` are not hoisted.

Comment: @loganfsmyth They **are** hoisted, that's why you get an exception ^^

Comment: Depends on how you look at it :) The initialization of the binding is not hoisted for `let`/`const`, but it is for `var` and function declarations. The declaration of a particular binding does affect the whole function/context though.

Comment: @loganfsmyth they are hoisted (since in the first example `a` would hide an `a` from outer scope, even before it is initialised), but accessing before initialisation throws an error.

Comment: @LimH. `arguments` is not an array and a parameter is a variable, not a value in an array.

Comment: @joews We may just be arguing over naming here. All bindings affect their whole execution context, so in that respect, the declaration is "hoisted", but in the sense of initialization, they are not. let/const bindings are not initialized until the declaration line has executed.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I agree. In my experience "hoisting" usually refers to the binding itself. The TDZ adds some interesting subtleties.

Comment: The first example will actually throw an error.

Comment: sorry guys, I thought I tested that first code snippet in chrome... I did test it, but maybe I changed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when using `const` there are still a few other places where one would encounter `undefined`.

- The value of an object property that has not been assigned.
- The default return of a function
- The result of the `void` operator.